# Power Query and Excel don't agree on sorting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, power-query

Take a table that has the following records

```
Field A
|
a
```

If I sort it with Excel, I get the pipe character before the "a"

```
Field A
|
a
```

Now, if I sort it with Power Query, I get

```
Field A
a
|
```

That can be a problem in some situations (for instance, i'm using the [double vlookup](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/04/23/how-much-faster-is-the-double-vlookup-trick/) trick for performance reason, and it gets messed by this discrepancy).

Here's a screenshot that illustrates the problem (it's actually wider than what I described above, because they also don't agree on the sorting of empty cells):

[image]

And [here's a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i9XHX4pnOjJ2Q87H_VX03mpNqMv7zMSP/view?usp=sharing) to this sample workbook.

So my questions are: is that a bug or a "feature"? And most of all, is there a way to make Power Query sort like Excel does?

**Edit 1**: it's actually much, much wider that this. In the sample file above, I updated it by adding a worksheet where I took all ASCII charachers from 32 (space) to 256:

[image]

The difference is obvious, even if we abstract the fact that Power Query is case sensible.
Excel sorts by what I would call a human-logical order (eg ä is next to a). But Power Query quite sorts by ascii code order, bu not completely. Messy.

Comment: They definitely have different sort orders, as is documented.  PQ is ASCII order, and Excel is not.  Pretty sure `VLOOKUP` depends on the Excel order.  I've not constructed a custom sort order for PQ, but it can be done.

Comment: I'd love to know where this is documented. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-sort (like all the MS PQ functions reference) is so poor.
Anyway, custom sorting is a nice odea, and it led my to this page (to which you also participated :) ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364388/power-query-sort-by-custom-list.
Will try it later, with a custom order being the one of the list on the left of my screenshot. Hope this will not have too much of a negative effect on the sorting speed.